# Why populating priority queue in java using Offer() populates it in alphabetical order while it also gives priority to capitalized words?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I am confused. Offer() populates the list in alphabetical order and that too it gives priority to capital words. How to populate the list in the order I type it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Bucky {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  PriorityQueue<String> q= new PriorityQueue<String>();
  q.offer("first");
  q.offer("aecond");
  q.offer("zhird");

  System.out.printf("%s ",q);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.printf("%s ", q.peek());
  System.out.println();


 }

}
```

o/p=
[aecond, first, zhird] 
aecond

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Bucky {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  PriorityQueue<String> q= new PriorityQueue<String>();
  q.offer("first");
  q.offer("aecond");
  q.offer("Zhird");

  System.out.printf("%s ",q);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.printf("%s ", q.peek());
  System.out.println();


 }

}
```

o/p= 
[Zhird, first, aecond] 
Zhird

Comment: It's sorted based on `String#compareTo`, which "*compares two strings lexicographically*" (based on unicode value). You would have to pass in your own comparator to change ordering.

Comment: I understand why uppercase has priority, but I'm confused by the reordering between `first` and `aecond`.

Comment: @shmosel That's because `iterator()` doesn't traverse the elements in any specific order. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): *The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())*

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: What a confusing documentation note. The iterator does in fact guarantee traversal order: the order in which items appear in the underlying array. What the note really means is that the iterator is not guaranteed to traverse the items in order by priority. And that's because there are multiple valid array representations of any binary heap that contains more than two elements.

Comment: @JimMischel I've read your answer and I find it great. I think it explains why the order is not guaranteed. I will upvote as soon as I can (ran out of votes today). I think that the doc note is clearly saying that the order is not guaranteed, it even says that it's not guaranteed to traverse the elements... in *any particular order*. It says nothing about priority. If the traversal order is implementation-specific, then it can't be guaranteed. Truth is that a priority queue is not meant to be used as a structure that imposes an order to it's elements, except for the first one.

Comment: @JimMischel It doesn't *guarantee* any such order as the order of the underlying array. It is free to use that order, and no doubt it does, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're questioning is the order of items in the array. That is, when you execute the line `System.out.printf("%s ",q);`, you get the output `[Zhird, first, aecond]`, and you're wondering why the second item in the array is `first`, when it is lexicographically larger than `aecond`.

The answer lies in how the priority queue is structured. It's structured as a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), and is subject to the way that a binary heap is constructed.

Your code constructs the heap like this:

```
q.offer("first");
q.offer("aecond");
q.offer("Zhird");
```

If we think of the heap as a tree, you can more easily see what happens. The first call places `"first"` at the root of the tree. The rules for creating a binary heap say that on the next call, the string `"aecond"` will be placed in the lowest, left-most position, and then the tree is rearranged. So first you have:

```
       "first"
      /
  "aecond"
```

Then, you work your way up the tree. If the child is smaller than the parent, then you swap parent and child. So in this case you end up with the tree:

```
       "aecond"
      /
  "first"
```

Now, the string `"Zhird"` comes along. It's added to the lowest, left-most position that's unoccupied:

```
       "aecond"
      /       \
  "first"   "Zhird"
```

And it's time again to rearrange the tree. `"Zhird"` is lexicographically smaller than `"aecond"`, so they're swapped:

```
       "Zhird"
      /       \
  "first"   "aecond"
```

Note that this is still a valid heap. The child nodes are larger than the parent.

The array representation of the binary heap is basically just a breadth-first traversal of the tree, so this tree is represented as `["Zhird", "first", "aecond"]`.

If you were to remove items from the heap one-by-one, you would get them in the proper order (i.e. "Zhird", "aecond", "first"). But the array representation can be much different than strict lexicographical order because the removal process rearranges the tree. In fact, if you were to remove the first item from the queue (i.e., call `q.poll`), and then output the array, you would see that it had been reordered to `["aecond", "first"]`.

See my blog, http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/29/a-better-way-to-do-it-the-heap/, for an explanation of the heap insertion and removal rules. See the follow-up article, http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/30/a-simple-heap-of-integers/, for an implementation that should help you understand how the tree is mapped to an array.

Also, if you were to populate the heap in this order:

```
q.offer("Zhird");
q.offer("first");
q.offer("aecond");
```

The output would be `[Zhird, first, aecond]`. But if your order was:

```
q.offer("Zhird");
q.offer("aecond");
q.offer("first");
```

The output would be `[Zhird, aecond, first]`.

Comment: Got it. But how do I print the list in the way I enter the terms? Is there any direct way, or do I have to print it like a tree in prefix order?

Comment: @Anuragkush: If you want to output the contents of the queue in priority order, then you either remove each item and output it, or you create a copy in a separate array, and sort it using the same comparator that you used to create the queue. Traversing the tree in prefix order would not give you the order you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the case, it is a simple as:

```
new PriorityQueue<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```